# How to change the value of multiple html attribute?

Tags: jquery, html

i want to change this html element.

`<a class="btn small fileupload_cancel" title="cancel upload">cancel upload</a>`

to

`<a class="btn small fileupload_cancel" title="remove all">remove all</a>`

what is the most feasible solution for this ?

thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should help you:

```
$("a.btn.small.fileupload_cancel").attr("title", "remove all").html("remove all");
```

Let me know if you need anything else..

Answer (score 4):

```
$('.fileupload_cancel').attr('title','remove all').text('remove all');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a.btn.small.fileupload_cancel').attr('title', 'remove all').text('remove all');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gPtMG/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a[title="cancel upload"]').html('remove all').attr('title','remove all');
```

See here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/ypzPD/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery .html() and .attr() functions here:

```
$('.classname').html($(this).attr('title'));
```

This will set the innerHTML of the selected object to the string in the title attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try -

```
$("a[title='cancel upload']").text('remove all').attr('title','remove all');
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/pcnwX/